# Lua - Exception has occurred: attempt to call a nil value

Tags: function, lua

I run the following code, but Lua keeps giving me "attempt to call a nil value". When I change the `_G[fi]` to `_G.fi` it gives me "attempt to call a string value".

```
i = "0"
j = "0"
k = "0"
fi = "f"..i
fj = "f"..j
fk= "f"..k
functions = {
       f1 = function(next, v) 
         for t = 1, 1, 4 do
        v[t] = v[t] + 1
        v[t] = v[t] % 3
        end
        if (next == "0") then return v 
        else return functions[next](0, v) end
      end,
       f2 = function(next, v) 
         for t = 1, 1, 4 do
        v[t] = v[t] + 2
        v[t] = v[t] % 3
        end
        if (next == "0") then return v
        else return functions[next](0, v) end
       end,
    f3 = function(next, v) 
        if (next == "0") then return v
        else return functions[next](0, v) end
    end,
    f4 = function(next, v) 
         swap(v[2], v[3])
        if (next == "0") then return v
        else return functions[next](0, v) end
    end,
    f5 = function(next, v) 
         swap(v[1], v[3])
        if (next == "0") then return v
        else return functions[next](0, v) end
    end,
    f6 = function(next, v) 
         swap(v[1], v[2])
        if (next == "0") then return v
        else return functions[next](0, v) end
    end,
}
for i = 0, 1, 6 do
        for j = 0, 1, 6 do
            for k = 0, 1, 6 do
                if _G[fi](fj, {1,2,0}) == _G[fj](fk, {1,2,0}) and not _G[fi](-1, {1,2,0}) == _G[fk](-1, {1,2,0}) then
                  print(i + " " + j + " " + k)
                  end
            end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you set `fi = "f"..i` at the start, which sets `fi == "f0"`, and that never changes for the rest of the program until you later invoke `_G[fi]`. The value of `fi` does not automatically change just because you changed the value of `i`.

You probably want to expand `i` (and `j` and `k`) at the call point, with something more like:

`_G["f"..i]("f"..j, {1,2,0})...` etc

Comment: Still gives me nil value.

Comment: @OceanMan post the new code and the exact error message?